# Disclosing geolocation positions to all users makes an app ineligible for the Apple Store?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, app-store, disclosure

I would like to know if the app I'd like to create has any chance to be eligible for the App Store.

The app  would temporarily store each user's geolocation information on a server and make it available to the other users of the app. This information will not reveal any other information on the user other than his geolocation. The user would be notified that the information will be shared with the other users. This information is useful for all users.

I asked Apple but they just gave me back the reference agreement without anymore information.

Do you know any app accepted in the App Store that provides this kind of feature ?
Or otherwise, what is your guess ?

Thanks in advance for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I'm reading your description correctly, it sounds like the Google Latitude app does something very similar.  And Apple's newly announced "Find My Friends" app does too (although that's an Apple app, and so may be exempt from their own rules ;) ).

IMHO as long as you are good about explaining to the user why their location data is needed and what it will be used for, and provide a strong privacy/data collection policy statement, etc. you should be fine.